# Looking for a story about people who live in a giant's teeth

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a story where people got eaten by a giant, and somehow managed to avoid being swallowed and live in the giant's teeth.

I believe that the main character was a man, who was caught by people who were already living in the teeth. I think that they had hollowed out the teeth?

I remember one scene where the main character regrets not being able to catch an old man, who got swallowed.

I think it was in a collection of stories. The cover might have been red? I read it around 2011, I think, although I think it was older than that.

Comment: This might be the *The Random House Book of Fantasy Stories* as per the post at http://pagesandpineapples.com/5-fantasy-books-influenced-my-childhood/ that mentions there being a story about living in a giant's teeth.

Comment: I have requested a copy via ILL to check.

Comment: I looked at the link and that looks like it is a different story than below since it came out a couple of years earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is ["The Giant's Tooth"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20797150-the-giant-s-tooth) by Bruce Coville.  It is collected in [*Odder than Ever*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1397949.Odder_Than_Ever).
[image][image]

I read it in an old copy of *Realms of Fantasy* and I found a list of stories from that period [here](http://www.philsp.com/homeville/fmi/t/t4609.htm).  Summary, such as it is:

> Edgar Twonky didn't intend to get eaten by a giant while he was heading for Cottleson Fair. Sometimes these things just happen. What was even more startling was what he discovered once he was in the giant's mouth . . .

I remember the story a bit.  I recall him saving several people and they eventually string a rope across the mouth to help save more.  I remember them carving out cavities (much to the giant's dismay) to make homes.  In the end, he falls out of the giant, then starts making plans on how to get back into the mouth.

Found this [preview at smashwords](https://www.smashwords.com/extreader/read/102155/1/the-giants-tooth).  Definitely the story I remembered.

The bit about the older man he fails to catch is this:

> While he continued to work on his new dwelling, Meagan taught him how to snatch things from the tide of food and rubble that poured down the giant's throat three times a day.  When she "went fishing," as she called it, she first secured a safety rope to one of the chairs inside the tooth.  Normally she pulled things in with the help of a long pole that had a hook on one end. But if something particularly good came rushing past that was too far out on the tongue for her to snag simply by leaning for it, she would fling her whole body onto the surface of the tongue, then use the rope to haul herself back.
>
> Once they saw an old man go past, but he was all the way in the center of the mouth, and they were not able to reach him despite their best efforts.  His cry of despair as he disappeared down the giant's gullet echoed in Edgar's dreams for many nights afterward.

Comment: Well spotted! :) I'll still check mine, but yours looks to be the right answer.